# How to execute my content script on a newly opened chrome tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am calling a Chrome extension from a web portal to open a URL in a new tab, and on the newly opened tab I want to perform `executeScript`:

**manifest.json**

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["http://localhost:3000/*"]
},
"permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
```

**background.js**

```
// listen to webportal
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    a = chrome.tabs.create({ url: request.openUrlInEditor });
    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(a.id, { file: "combined.css" });
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(a.id, { file: "combined.js" });
  }
);
```

If I try to perform `insertCSS` and `executeScript` on extension click,
it works fine

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab.id, { file: "combined.css" });
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: "combined.js" });
});
```

Comment: What are your permissions? I mean right now the structure is simply wrong, with `permissions` being a subkey of `externally_connectable`.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, updated now

Comment: Note that you don't need the `tabs` permission for what you're doing (it's only needed to read URLs/titles of existing tabs)

Comment: the extension is performing someother functionalities also, tabs permission have been added for those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved my problem myself
worked after giving active tabs permission to my extension
**manifest.json**

```
    "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*","activeTab"]
```

**backround.js**

```
// listen to webportal
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: request.openUrl },function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab.id, { file: "combined.css" });
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: "combined.js" });
    });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`chrome.tabs.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create) doesn't return anything.

To make use of the created tab, you could wrap your method inside its callback, which has the created tab as a parameter:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: request.openUrlInEditor }, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab.id, { file: "combined.css" });
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: "combined.js" });
    });
));
```

Comment: @shubhangisingh, could you please make sure `onMessageExternal.addListener` is called?

Comment: yes its being called

`chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: request.openUrlInEditor });

    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "Click" } );
    setTimeout(function () {
      chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText( { text: "" } );
    }, 5000);
    
    
  }
);`
this is working for me

Comment: @shubhangisingh, I guess you haven't declared  corresponding `permissions` in `manifest.json`, could you please also provide `permissions` field in your `manifest.json`?

Comment: i have edited to question to inculde the permissions section in my mainfest

Comment: If `executeScript` fails for some reason, it will raise an exception. Do open the background console to check for that.

Answer (score 0):

**Content.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(buttonClicked)
function buttonClicked(tab) {
   console.log("button clicked", tab)
   chrome.tabs.create({ url: LinkOfNewTab }, function(tab2) {
   console.log(tab2)
   extensionButtonClicked = true
})
```

}

**Background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId,changeInfo,tab){
if (extensionButtonClicked) {
    if (tab.url === Link1) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content.js"} );
    }

    if (tab.url === Link2) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content2.js"} );
    }
}
```

});

**Description**

```
'chrome.browserAction.onClicked' event will listen for icon when you click and 'chrome.tabs.create' will open up a new code and 'chrome.tabs.onUpdated' will fire every time when page reload or new tab is opened.
```