# Execute content script on a newly opened chrome tab that redirects to another URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, code-injection

My problem is like this one
[How to execute my content script on a newly opened chrome tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38219800/how-to-execute-my-content-script-on-a-newly-opened-chrome-tab)
but my newly tab is redirected to another URL and I need to run my script at this redirected URL.

```js
chrome.tabs.create({
    url: url
}, function (newTab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(newTab.id, {code: "alert('ok')"});
});
```

the problem is: the alert does not run in the newly created tab neither the redirected one.

`"permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*","activeTab"]`

Comment: Wait for the tab to load, [example](/a/44864966). If it's redirecting, you can add a check for the URL.

Comment: Your solution works, but there is another problem.
The injected script does not capture the desired `window` object in the newly opened tab. 

https://codeshare.io/GqWNbz

Did you know if is possible to capture the correct window scope object?

Comment: That's because content scripts run in an isolated world. You need to insert a `<script>` element to access the page variables, see [this answer](/a/9517879).

Comment: The only way I could get it to work :/
https://codeshare.io/24vAWE
It's HORRIBLE, but works

Comment: There's no need for `eval`. Seriously.

Comment: But without it i get undefined error (i dont know why)

Comment: if I just call `cleanFilters()` does not work.

Comment: No need to call it. It automatically runs when you append the script. Also no need for  cleanFilters either, simply use script.textContent = "globalFilter.cleanFilters()"

Comment: unfortunately doesn't worked

Comment: Well it means you did it wrong :-) or the code runs too early, maybe setTimeout is needed. Where is globalFilter defined? Is it in your content script or in the site?

Comment: It is in the site